# JAXB customization binding

Tags: jaxb, customization, xjc

I have below complextype

```
<xsd:complexType name="cidType"> 
  <xsd:choice> 
    <xsd:sequence> 
      <xsd:element name="a" type="Type_A"></xsd:element> 
      <xsd:element name="b" type="Type_B"></xsd:element> 
    </xsd:sequence> 
      <xsd:element name="b" type="Type_B"></xsd:element> 
  </xsd:choice> 
</xsd:complexType>
```

When trying to generate JAXB classes for this schema it's wrong, because, as you see, is repeated reference to the element b the JAXB error gives me is:

/* 
     * You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason: 
     * The field name "b" is used by two different parts of a schema. 
*/

Since it is an industry standard schema I don't have the liberty to change anything. What is the possible solution?

If i go the customization route, i don't know how to, if possible please point me to a good resource/example. I have already tried my luck with google

I do have an external binding declaration to incorporate data type for some of the elements, but I am not sure how I can use the binding customization to solve my current problem

Comment: What is standardized? The class representation or the schema? If only the schema is standardized you can name the properties as you like as long as they get serialized back to the correct XML element.

Comment: schema is standardized, how do I rename the properties and make sure that they are serialized back to the correct element.?

Comment: Note: element b is actually the same element and should represent the same value

Comment: IMHO that doesn't make sense. AFAIK you can not force two field to have the same value using a XML schema in that way.

Comment: what I am trying to say is, that i want to have only 1 property in the jaxb class to represent "b"

Comment: because of the sequence you can have 0..n occurrences of "a" and "b" - therefore 1 property is not enough...